# Problem accessing object attributes from a pointer class attribute

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have the following class:

```
class Customer {

private:
    string name;
    savingAccount *savingsAccount = nullptr;
public:
   void setSavingsAccount(savingAccount savingsAccount);
   savingAccount* getSavingsAccount();
```

And methods:

```
savingAccount* Customer::getSavingsAccount()
{
    return this->savingsAccount;
}

void Customer::setSavingsAccount(savingAccount savingsAccount)
{
    this->savingsAccount = &savingsAccount;
}
```

savingsAccount class is derived from account struct:

```
struct account {
private:
    double balance;
    double interestRate;
    double interest;
    const string accountType = "Base Account";

public:
    account();
    double getBalance();
    double getIntRate();
    double calculateInterest(int n);
    void setBalance(double balance);
    void setIntRate(double rate);
    string getType();

};

class savingAccount : public account {
public:
    double savingDepositArr[5];
    const string accountType = "Saving Account";
```

Now the problem:
I am creating SavingsAccount and Customer objects.

```
savingAccount newSavingAccount;
Customer customer;
customer.setSavingsAccount(newSavingAccount);
```

When I try to access anything through getSavingsAccount I can't.

```
customer.getSavingsAccount.getBalance()
customer.getSavingsAccount().getBalance()
```

or

```
customer.getSavingsAccount.accountType
```

I am 100% sure I am not using the pointer the right way. I have been looking for a solution for a long time, however still nothing. If I remove the pointers and just have the object as an attribute, it works but this is not the solution I am looking for. I just want to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Customer::getSavingsAccount()` returns a **pointer** to a `savingAccount` object.  To access members of that object, you need to dereference the pointer using the `*` operator, and then access the members using the `.` operator.  Or, you can use the shorter `->` operator:

```cpp
(*customer.getSavingsAccount()).getBalance()
customer.getSavingsAccount()->getBalance()
```

That being said, be aware that `Customer::setSavingsAccount()` takes in a `savingAccount` object **by value**, so a *copy* of the input object is passed in.  `setSavingsAccount()` saves a pointer to that *copy*.  When `setSavingsAccount()` exits, the *copy* gets destroyed, leaving the pointer *dangling* pointing at invalid memory.  Thus, anything you try to do afterwards that involves dereferencing that pointer will cause **undefined behavior**.

For what you are attempting to do, make `setSavingsAccount()` take the `savingAccount` object **by reference** instead, eg:

```cpp
class Customer {
private:
    ...
    savingAccount *savingsAccount = nullptr;
public:
   void setSavingsAccount(savingAccount &savingsAccount);
   ...
};

void Customer::setSavingsAccount(savingAccount &savingsAccount)
{
    this->savingsAccount = &savingsAccount;
}
```

Just make sure the input `savingAccount` object outlives the `Customer` object, or else you will still end up with a *dangling* pointer.

An alternative solution would be to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Customer {
private:
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<savingAccount> savingsAccount;
public:
   void setSavingsAccount(std::unique_ptr<savingAccount> savingsAccount);
   savingAccount* getSavingsAccount();
};

savingAccount* Customer::getSavingsAccount()
{
    return this->savingsAccount.get();
}

void Customer::setSavingsAccount(std::unique_ptr<savingAccount> savingsAccount)
{
    this->savingsAccount = std::move(savingsAccount);
}
```

```cpp
auto newSavingAccount = std::make_unique<savingAccount>();
Customer customer;
customer.setSavingsAccount(std::move(newSavingAccount));
...
customer.getSavingsAccount()->getBalance();
customer.getSavingsAccount()->accountType;
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Customer {
private:
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<savingAccount> savingsAccount;
public:
   void setSavingsAccount(std::shared_ptr<savingAccount> savingsAccount);
   std::shared_ptr<savingAccount> getSavingsAccount();
};

std:shared_ptr<savingAccount> Customer::getSavingsAccount()
{
    return this->savingsAccount;
}

void Customer::setSavingsAccount(std::shared_ptr<savingAccount> savingsAccount)
{
    this->savingsAccount = savingsAccount;
}
```

```cpp
auto newSavingAccount = std::make_shared<savingAccount>();
Customer customer;
customer.setSavingsAccount(newSavingAccount);
...
customer.getSavingsAccount()->getBalance();
customer.getSavingsAccount()->accountType;
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding object by reference did the trick. Thanks for pointing out that when I pass an object it gets destroyed. I will try to remember that.

Answer (score 1):

`getSavingsAccount()` returns a pointer to a savings account. If you are working with a pointer to an object, you can't access the attributes with `.` (unless you dereference). You can access the attributes (without dereferencing) via the shorthand `->`.

Try `customer.getSavingsAccount()->getBalance()`

Comment: `->` still dereferences the pointer, it is just doing the job of two operators `*` and `.` put together.

Comment: This is building, however the values are not right. The array where I store the balance has values of `-9.25596e+61`

Comment: I see that you resolved you issue by passing by reference. In general, it is good practice to pass your objects by reference, not only to avoid the dangling pointer problem, but it is much more efficient. Instead of copying a (potentially large) object, we merely pass along the 8 byte address which is much more efficient.